# Spring with Hibernate, join data from another table and map to a new helper object

Tags: hibernate, spring, join

first i have to say i am quite new with spring and hibernate.

now my situation: i have one table named Places which has: Id PK, name and description.
i have a second table named Edges which has: ID PK, fromPlaces (fk to the pk id from places), and toPlaces (also referenced to the id from places).

now i want to make a query which will eventually map to an object which will have my Edge object plus both the names of the fromPlace reference and toPlaces reference.

currently i have this in my DAO which is functioning properly:

```
public List<Edge> listEdges() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Edge")
            .list();
}
```

Please any good tutorial or any code examples you can give me to help me with the process of building what i need. i dont know if its helpful but i am using annotations to wire everything.

**SECOND EDIT:** ADding the solution to my classes for both referencing and afterwards if a Place is removed to automatically remove the references to Edge objects.

```
   @Entity
@Table(name="PLACES")
public class Place {

        @Id
        @Column(name="ID")
        @GeneratedValue
        private Integer id;

        @Column(name="NAME")
        private String name;

        @Column(name="DESCRIPTION")
        private String description;

        @Column(name="IMAGEURL")
        private String imageUrl;

        @Column(name="ISVALIDDESTINATION")
        @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
        private boolean validDestination;

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "FROMPLACE_ID")
        private Set<Edge> fromPlace = new HashSet<Edge>(0);

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "TOPLACE_ID")
        private Set<Edge> toPlace = new HashSet<Edge>(0);
```

And this is my edge model: note i am ommiting the getters and setters here because they have no annotations,they are just standard.

```
   @Entity
    @Table(name = "EDGES")
    public class Edge {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "ID")
        @GeneratedValue
        private Integer id;

        @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name="FROMPLACE_ID")
    private Place fromPlace;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name="TOPLACE_ID")
    private Place toPlace;

        @Column(name="COST")
        private Integer cost;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of, you need to map your entities. ["Hibernate Annotations" docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/) are a good place to start.

Links from `Edge` to `Places` (BTW, naming your entities in plural is confusing; I think that's why **duffymo** suggested collections) should be mapped as `@ManyToOne`

Once you do that, your `listEdges` method above would return a list of `Edge` objects, each of which would have (possibly lazily populated) `getFromPlaces()` and `getToPlaces()` methods returning appropriate `Places` instances.

Now, if you want to return a *separate* helper object that contains `Edge` and only *names* of relevant `Places` entities, you'll have to create that object along with appropriate constructor and write a query [referencing that constructor](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select).

This is a bit more advanced, though - I'd recommend you get the first part working and look into working with lazy associations before you proceed with this.

**Edit (based on question update):**

Your `Edge` mapping should instead be something like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EDGES")
public class Edge {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="FROMPLACE")
    private Place fromPlace;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="TOPLACE")
    private Place toPlace;
}
```

Note that it's not necessary to specify `@Column` on fields whose name matches column name. Also note that it's common to use "_ID" suffix to indicate foreign keys (e.g. "FROMPLACE_ID") - if you do that, you can omit `@JoinColumn` declarations as well.

Comment: places was a typo. my objects are Place and Edge. also i was looking about mapping in this tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/. is this the way to go? i kinda got confused by what you said about getFromPlaces returning a place object. i have fromPlaces defined as an integer containing the referenced id from places. i will edit my code with the models.

Comment: i found this i think will do what i need according to your explanation. http://www.vaannila.com/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-many-to-one-using-annotations-1.html

Comment: @DArkO - you should map _entity_ (object), not its identifier. Example in your above comment works; Hibernate Annotations docs have plenty of samples as well: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-association

Comment: OK please one more thing. how can i remove the ascociated edge rows when i remove a place that is a fk in some edge row?

Comment: OK nevermind i figured it out. i have added this to my question in case someone needs it. tanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Stop thinking less in terms of tables and more in terms of objects.

You need an Edge object with 1:m relationships to Place references, to and from.

Comment: ok but is my case really one to many relationship? i can just have 1 match for toPlace and 1 match for fromPlace? so the answer wound be something like defining 2 new place objects with a relationship (oneToMany or oneToOne ) in the Edge model that will map to the toPlace integer column?

Comment: Still too much about tables and not enough about objects.  Two collections of Place - to and from.  Let Hibernate figure out how to populate the two 1:m relationships.

Comment: DArkO has foreign keys to both "from" and "to Places". They can't possibly be collections, they should be mapped as @ManyToOne instead.